# Android: how to identify modified files on sdcard?

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard, last-modified

My android app is saving some file on the sdcard / external storage. Some of these files may then get modified by the user outside the control of my app.

At a later point I would like to identify which files were modified since they were initially created.

Normally this would be easy: simply check the last modified time. Unfortunately an [android bug prevents changing the last modified time](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18624) of existing files.

How does everybody else work around this problem? Clearly cloud sync apps like Dropbox etc have found a way. Do I really need to calculate a hash for every file just to find out whether it has changed?

Comment: Why dont you save them in internal memory?

Comment: Your link is useless as it needs a login.

Comment: @greenapps The files are too many/large to restrict users to the internal memory.

Comment: @greenapps The link is to the official Google Android bug-tracker. I am afraid you will have to take their access-policy up with them directly. There is nothing I can do about that.

Comment: So you are too lazy to give a decent problem description and expect me to go through the trouble of creating an account. Interesting attitude.